# Different `OnTimestampSet` config for solo and para chains

Tags: pallet

I noticed that the `OnTimestampSet` differs in the parachains and solo chains. This config must be set in the solo chain as `Aura` or `Babe`. But in parachain, `()` is okay.

In Cumulus:

```rs
impl pallet_timestamp::Config for Runtime {
    /// A timestamp: milliseconds since the unix epoch.
    type Moment = u64;
    type OnTimestampSet = ();   // here
    type MinimumPeriod = MinimumPeriod;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

In substrate-node-template:

```rs
impl pallet_timestamp::Config for Runtime {
    /// A timestamp: milliseconds since the unix epoch.
    type Moment = u64;
    type OnTimestampSet = Aura;  // here
    type MinimumPeriod = ConstU64<{ SLOT_DURATION / 2 }>;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

From the docs in the pallet-timestamp:

```rs
/// Set the current time.
///
/// This call should be invoked exactly once per block. It will panic at the finalization
/// phase, if this call hasn't been invoked by that time.
///
/// The timestamp should be greater than the previous one by the amount specified by
/// `MinimumPeriod`.
///
pub fn set(origin: OriginFor<T>, #[pallet::compact] now: T::Moment) -> DispatchResult {...}
```

What make this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What make this difference?

This was actually wrong, thank you for bringing this up. On Parachains the `OnTimestampSet` should be set to `Aura` as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to "How parachains produce block", you could get more info from [polkadot wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parachains#what-is-parachain-consensus) and [the path of a parachain block](https://polkadot.network/blog/the-path-of-a-parachain-block/).

Aura primarily provides block authoring in solo chains, but in parachains, block producer is **collator**.

Comment: Is that meant he collators do not need to set a timestamp when sealing a block? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Substrate does not have the concept of "a block timestamp". You could get the timestamp of a block via `timestamp.now()` with block hash. Refer to [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/2811)